# Number of ways of arranging $2$m people, m of which wear different coloured shirts, subject to the following conditions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> There are $2m$ people, $m$ wearing red shirts and $m$ wearing blue. The number of ways in which these $2m$ people can stand in a queue, such that at any instant a person standing in queue sees more number of red shirt people standing in front of him than blue shirt people is ____?

I couldn't come up with a constraint for this problem. My initial approach was to place a red shirted person at the head of the queue and a blue shirted person at the tail, then arrange the people left over in the middle. There are $\binom{2m-2}{m-1}$ ways of doing this. This doesn't work out, because we may have the case $\mathrm{RBBBB....B}$, where the fourth and fifth individuals see more blue shirts in front of them

The answer mentioned (without an explanation) is

> $$\frac{1}{m+1}\binom{2m}{m}$$

I could not reverse engineer this, nor see why this is the correct answer. Any hints/solutions are appreciated!

Comment: This is a [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) problem.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction @N.F.Taussig. I'll read more about this and post an answer on my own.

Comment: The spoiler tag gives a math processing error for me.

Comment: What you want is stated as [Bertrand's ballot problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem) solved using the popularly-known reflection principle. Check the approach in the link. I once wrote [an article](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XbzgzFK1dnhMu3zfRFX_s-OOG5LalAgq/view?usp=sharing) explaining the approach to understand it better myself.